# java code to read 3 CSV

Tags: java

How do I write java code to read 3 CSV files A.csv, B.csv, C.csv and determine if files A and B have any duplicates:

```
 import java.util.scanner;
 import java.io.file;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundExceptions;   
 public class CSV {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FilesNotFoundExceptions {   
        File f = new File ("A.csv")
        scanner in p = new Scanner ();
        while (input A. has Next()
```

Comment: Do you want us to write this for you or are you stuck? Need more context. And we need to see that you put forth some effort already.

Comment: I am stuck and I think that I am going to need help writing the code.  I guess step one is:  do I need to create three separate data files in java and pull them into my code?

Comment: @bananacakes, if you are determining if A and B have any duplicates, why do you need C?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a homework problem, so I will not post any code. And you should also try to post code that you've tried. This will help others to help you.

Here's my attempt to help you with the limited info that I have.

---

At a high level, you need to do the following:

1. Read File A.(you have got a good start already on this.)
2. Create a List object, for example, `java.util.ArrayList`.
3. Read each line in A as a string, and add it to the above `List`.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 for File B.

Now you have two lists - say listA and listB.

To compare the two lists,

1. use a `for` loop to iterate through listA.
2. get each String in listA and see if `listB.contains(string_from_listA)`.
3. if step 2 is true, use a counter or print the common line.

There you go. Just use the above algorithm to implement your code in Java. If you get stuck somewhere specific. Post the question and someone would try to help you!

---

Hope this helps!